# how to identify subchild elements using xpath

Tags: xpath

How to identify the subchild element using xpath. 
I need xpath for the below class. xml Path is in attached image.

```
<div class="listing_section clearFix ng-scope" 
and <div class="clearFix">
```

I tried with xpath=`//div[@class='bus_listing']//div[@startswith(@class,'listing_section')]` and `xpath=//div[@class='bus_listing']/descendant::div[@starts-with(@class,'listing_section')]` but both are not working

[image]

Comment: Could you please format your question in a readable way? What class? What image?

Comment: I need the xpath of two classes in a di. 1 )<div class="listing_section clearFix ng-scope"  and 2nd is <div class="clearFix">. Path is already in image.

Comment: hi @Sak can you please en large the image and send

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `@` at the beginning of `starts-with` function, try this way :

```
//div[@class='bus_listing']//div[starts-with(@class,'listing_section')]
```

and to get the highlighted `<div class="clearFix">` :

```
//div[@class='bus_listing']//div[starts-with(@class,'listing_section')]/div[@class='clearFix']
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i tried with both xpaths but it didn't work